# How to adjust the height of document viewer in IPOD using titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have PDF , to view that pdf i have used document viewer

`var viewer = Ti.UI.iOS.createDocumentViewer({
    url:"Barcode.pdf",
    height:'100%',
    bottom:0
});
viewer.show();`

The pdf will be displayed as center, top as title bar, but bottom as empty, I am unable to set the height as 100%. I have also used `Ti.UI.FILL` but still no use. Can any one please share the ideas.

Thanks in Advance,

Swathi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is correct. The height of your viewer component is filling the height of the parent component.

The issue you have is related to the specific pdf document you're using. I don't know which is the ratio (width/height) of your document, but if it's greater then your device screen ratio you will have something like this:
[image: documentRatio > iPhoneScreenRatio]

If you try to zoom in then the entire screen of your device will be used!

Only in two cases the entire screen will be completely used:

- if the **document ratio is smaller then the screen ratio** (try with a document with a very small width)
- if the **document has many pages**

If you are in the first case (document ratio > device screen ratio) and you want to have a well designed page then I suggest to just center the DocumentViewer instead of setting the height to 100%

Comment: Thanks Riccardo Bucco, If I have multiple pages, displaying correctly.Thanks for ur explanation. and I have one more doubt is there any possibility to open remote pdf file, need print that file. Any Ideas?

Comment: First of all you have to download the desired file (through a simple http request). Then you have to store it in the filesystem (usually in the application data directory). At this point you can use DocumentViewer to open it. Unfortunately DocumentViewer accepts only local paths!

Comment: Is there any other way to print the file in IOS without sockets?

Comment: Just use a WebView!! It can also print PDF documents! This is the most simple thing you can do... However open other questions instead of asking different things as a comment